# React + Redux + React Navigation 2.0: connect() or withNavigation() first?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

Couldn't find it in the docs: What is the best practice when using React Navigation together with Redux?

Should you do 1.:

```
export default withNavigation(connect(
  mapStateToProps, 
  { someFunction }
)(SomeComponent))
```

Or 2.:

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps, 
  { someFunction }
)(withNavigation(SomeComponent))
```

?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After some googling it seems to be that 1. is the best practice.

Comment: Can you share a link to where you found this information please? I'm working out something similar with redux and react-navigation. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry it was to long ago, I don't have the links any more. I remember reading something on Medium.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I got my issue sorted just 3 minutes ago.

Comment: Too sad, your method doesn't on React Native

Comment: @HauLuu It doesn't what? Work? For me it does work in React Native.

Comment: @J.Hesters Yeah, It works on my React Native project now. But it didn't yesterday,  re-installing the react navigation lib solve the problem. Sorry I didn't capture the error log. It just say something like (0, react navigation) is not function.